# Recognize rectangle in a document

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I have some documents in jpg with at the end a rectangle and inside a signature. I would like to crop the image where the rectangle is and save it. 
I tried to use the AForge library but I have some problems in recognizing the rectangle in the documents.

```
ColorFiltering colorFilter = new ColorFiltering();

colorFilter.Red = new IntRange(0, 64);
colorFilter.Green = new IntRange(0, 64);
colorFilter.Blue = new IntRange(0, 64);
colorFilter.FillOutsideRange = false;
colorFilter.ApplyInPlace(bitmapData);

BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
blobCounter.MinHeight = 5;
blobCounter.MinWidth = 5;

blobCounter.ProcessImage(bitmapData);
Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
```

I think I need to apply some filters but I have no idea which one to use.

Comment: Get the sample from GitHub.  See msdn : https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PdfDocument

Answer (score 0):

There is a full Aforge.net tutorial for that.

- [Rectangles, squares, equilateral triangles, etc.](http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/shape_checker/)
- [Blobs Processing](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/blobs_processing.html)

In the first link, you have:

> ```
> // dictionary of color to highlight different shapes
> Dictionary<PolygonSubType, Color> colors =
>     new Dictionary<PolygonSubType, Color>( );
>
> colors.Add( PolygonSubType.Unknown, Color.White );
> colors.Add( PolygonSubType.Trapezoid, Color.Orange );
> colors.Add( PolygonSubType.Parallelogram, Color.Red );
> colors.Add( PolygonSubType.Rectangle, Color.Green );
> colors.Add( PolygonSubType.Square, Color.Blue );
> colors.Add( PolygonSubType.Rhombus, Color.Gray );
>
> colors.Add( PolygonSubType.EquilateralTriangle, Color.Pink );
> colors.Add( PolygonSubType.IsoscelesTriangle, Color.Purple );
> colors.Add( PolygonSubType.RectangledTriangle, Color.SkyBlue );
> colors.Add( PolygonSubType.RectangledIsoscelesTriangle, Color.SeaGreen );
>
> for ( int i = 0, n = blobs.Length; i < n; i++ )
> {
>     List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints( blobs[i] );
>     List<IntPoint> corners;
>
>     if ( shapeChecker.IsConvexPolygon( edgePoints, out corners ) )
>     {
>         // check subtype
>         PolygonSubType subType = shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType( corners );
>
>         using ( Pen pen = new Pen( colors[subType], 2 ) )
>         {
>             g.DrawPolygon( pen, ToPointsArray( corners ) );
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

So, you, basically, have to make use of [CheckPolygonSubType()](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/fcdbd1fe-8828-af0a-9379-2ebf429a27f9.htm) - method.